# Java Conditional configuration (web.xml) - Development/Production

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web.xml, production-environment

I have the following configuration in my `web.xml`file in a Spring application:

```
<session-config>
   <cookie-config>
      <name>mycookie</name>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
      <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>       
</session-config>
```

The problem is: the `<secure>true</secure>` enforces the cookie to be sent over HTTPS only, and in my development machine I don't have HTTPS set up. However, this configuration is indispensable in the production environment.

Is there a way to make this configuration to be environment-sensitive - i.e. `false` for development and `true` for official/production builds?

Comment: I would do it the other way around: make your development machine supporting HTTPS. (It is relative easy for Tomcat with an self signed certificate).

Comment: @Ralph and gets even easier with real certificates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Maven (which I would strongly suggest) then you can use profiles together with [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/). You can specify different `web.xml` in each of these profiles (so you can have one for prod environment and other for dev). Here is an example for you

```
<properties>
    <webXmlPath>path/to/your/dev/xml</webXmlPath>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <webXmlPath>path/to/prod/webXml</webXmlPath>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>${webXmlPath}</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now each build will have by default `web.xml` with dev settings. When you want to change it to production build, just execute

```
mvn clean install -Pprod
```

Comment: That's a simple and interesting solution! Very useful when there are many configuration differences between production and development.

Answer (score 4):

The solution was very simple using a propety:

```
<secure>${session.cookie.secure}</secure>
```

In my development `.properties` file I added:

```
session.cookie.secure=false
```

And in test/production I can set it to `true`